# How do you create an external URL link to a tab and check a radio button?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, radio-button

I would like to create a custom URL link like the [1](http://www.cloudtech.co.uk/mytabpage.php#menu2) below that can not only link to a menu tab, but also select a radio item within that tab. At the moment the link I have can only point to a specific tab on the page and not an item too. How can I create a link with both? Visit links below and/or Codepen -

What I have so far: http://www.cloudtech.co.uk/mytabpage.php#menu2

What I would like: 1. http://www.cloudtech.co.uk/mytabpage.php#menu2#item3

```
Codepen: https://codepen.io/cloudtechuk/pen/KBqNdR
```

Comment: Since you're using PHP, you can pass a variable in the URL as a $_GET and write a function if this variable is set to have the radiobox checked; in essence http://www.cloudtech.co.uk/mytabpage.php?item2=true#menu2 and have a $_GET['item2'] variable and check if it was passed if so you can echo selected attribute into the field you need. This can also be done in JS btw by getting the URL parameters and using a function to do the same; though I recommend PHP; much easier; hope this helps!